# set of equidistant points from two points A and B always intersect (A+B)/2 in any $L_p$ norm?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I have a problem proving when $d_p(A,x)=d_p(B,x)$, meaning x is equidistant set, x always intersects $(A+B)/2$  (midpoint).
$d_p(A,x)$ is the $p^{th}$ Minkowski norm.

I have plotted a figure for different $L_p$ norms below. Is there a way to prove that? 
ADDITIONAL NOTE: I am new on this topic and also on this forum. I am not a mathematician but an engineer. Any suggestion on an academic paper or a text book related to this topic also appreciated.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzTQC.png

Comment: I am actually trying to understand that $d_p(A,x)-d_p(B,x)=0$ and $d_q(A,x)-d_q(B,x)=0$ and $p\neq q$ is satisfied only when x=(A+B)/2.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret the question correctly, you are asking why the arithmetical mean $x=\frac{A+B}2$ has the same distance to $A$ and $B$.

This holds actually in any normed space: Just note that
$$A-x=\frac{A-B}2=x-B\text,$$
which readily implies $\lVert A-x\rVert=\lVert x-B\rVert$.

Comment: I am actually trying to understand that $d_p(A,x)-d_p(B,x)=0$ and $d_q(A,x)-d_q(B,x)=0$ and $p\neq q$ is satisfied only when x=(A+B)/2.

Comment: So your question is whether the arithmetical mean is the *only* point having the same distance for $A$ and $B$ for two different $p$-norms? This is not the case, in general: For instance in $\mathbb R^2$, $A=(1,1)$, $B=(0,0)$, the point $x=(0,1)$ satisfies $A-x=(1,0)$ and $x-B=(0,1)$ and thus has the same distance to $A$ and $B$ for any norm which does not change under permutations of the coordinates. It seems to me that also in your computer plot there are two further points besides the arithmetical mean which are in the intersection of all plotted lines.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I need to edit my question such that "an equidistant set of two points always intersect the line segment between them on the arithmetic mean in any lp norm". Your comment made it clear now.